# Significant Kaplan-meier curves

Tags: r, statistical-significance, survival, inference, cox-model

I am currently doing some research on cardiac arrests in R.
I've constructed some Kaplan-Meier curves, which showed me a significant p-value for the log-rank test.
But after visual inspection I can not comprehend how that is possible, as the graphs are overlappin almost constantly. I have tried univariable Cox regression, which also gives me a significant result.[image]

I am aware that this also violates the proportional hazards assumption. Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Comment: There's a  substantial difference in survival in the lowest survival times -- say somewhere in the ballpark of  t=0.04 ish, and a very quick-and-rough mental calculation suggests that the p-value seems reasonable. You should label your y-axis, (especially since it's not showing $\hat{S}(x)$.).

Answer (score 1):

When you have many hundreds of events, as you seem to, even a small absolute difference in survival cam lead to "statistical significance." You need to apply your understanding of the subject matter to determine whether the differences are practically significant.

The log-rank test comparing two groups is equivalent to the score test for a Cox model with the groups as the predictor variable. You thus should get similar estimates of statistical significance, as you do.

Yes, the crossing of curves suggests that the proportional hazards assumption doesn't hold for a simple model using only `IHCA` versus `OHCA` status as a predictor. The Cox model will provide a type of event-averaged hazard ratio, in this case probably emphasizing the large number of early events. That hazard ratio, however, clearly doesn't describe your data adequately.

A more complete model, however, might resolve the proportional-hazards issue. Omission or improper modeling of outcome-associated predictors can lead to this type of observation. For example, if the `OHCA` individuals tended to be younger than those in the `IHCA` group and your outcome is the cumulative probability of death following an initial cardiac arrest, then the later crossing of the curves could just be due to omission of `age` as a predictor from the model.

With this large a data set you could consider incorporating up to a few dozen outcome-associated variables to help account for things other than `IHCA/OHCA`. See Frank Harrell's notes on [Regression Modeling Strategies](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/) for suggestions on how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

The word "significant" often just confuses things. Eliminate it from your thinking. It can be confusing because it has two meanings. One meaning is that the p-value is less than a preset threshold (often 0.05). The other meaning is "big enough to matter". Those two meanings are quite different, so it is best to avoid that word (or at least precede with "statistically" when you intend the first meaning).

First look at the graph. The two survival curves are nearly identical. That is your conclusion. (Of course, I am saying this not knowing what the two treatments are, what background information you have, why this study was done,...so I am likely missing nuance.).

The smallish p value means if all differences were due to chance and all the assumptions of the survival analysis are met, you'd rarely expect to see a difference between curves as large or larger than you saw. In other words, the difference you got is more than you'd often see by random sampling alone. But if the difference between curves is biologically trivial, the p value may be more of a distraction than an important part of the analysis.